# How to fix boolean cut failures?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edges

I refer to the Blender built-in boolean tool described [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html).

I am cutting a complex surface > 30 000 facets.  All the cuts are along coplanar surfaces.  About 50 % of the cuts fail.

In the detail of the cut file posted, you can see that the boolean cut seems to be done, but that the tris are not removed.

What can I do to ensure that the boolean cuts do not fail, or is there an easy way to remove the tris after the cut failed?

See this large [sample cut file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sftunQi2G_vwoUe0KWjnFZNxBFXORY2-/view?usp=sharing).

*Overall shape*
[image]

*Detail*
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Would you mind adding one or two images? For those of us with bad imagination.

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ added a sample file.

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟThanks for generating the detail.

Comment: You can upload your .blend file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To repair this kind of damage I would select all and press <kbd>X</kbd> (Delete) to start from scratch.

Very similar result you can get easier without booleans and with clean topology by shrinkwraped edges over your terrain.

- Add plane, slice it by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> with value of desired amounth of cuts
- Select one short edge, search for *Select Similar > Lenght* and delete them (<kbd>X</kbd>)
- Subdivide all long edges in amount of desired detail
- Rotate in desired angle of `Z` axis
- Add *Shrink Wrap* modifier with Projection type, Target your terrain, `Z` axis, Positive, Apply
- Select all vertices, Extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>) in `Z` axis, move below terrain level, Scale in `Z` to `0`
- Add *Solidify* modifier to get thickness

Simplified sketch of proces
[image]

Hires model (1000 slices)
[image]

[image]

Comment: I also needed some non-manifold culls.  The main challenge that remained was to add a solid base at the bottom.  A 0,1 mm overlap ensures no co-planar fails with a boolean union.

Answer (score 4):

Let me post a new answer, showing how to simply repair the mesh.

1. Select the faces that weren't deleted and delete them <kbd>X</kbd> > Delete Faces
2. Select the two side edges and bridge them with a new face *Vertex > New Face*, <kbd>F</kbd>
3. Select bottom edge loop <kbd>Alt + LMB</kbd>, and also fill it with a new face <kbd>F</kbd>

I'm well aware your mesh is more complicated, but I used the exact same approach to repair two of the errors there.

[image]

When the edge is missing in some places, just connect the vertices, before you continue.
*Vertex > Connect Vertex Path*
Shortcut: <kbd>J</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I like your examples a lot.  It shows the process clearly.  If there are no better answers, +50 will be yours.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm glad you like them :).

Answer (score 2):

CTRL+T works in edit mode to triangulate the mesh. Blender boolean operations function best on *triangulated* mesh, so doing this will improve your boolean. 
One more thing: you may want to do a limited dissolve function on the boolean being cut, so that the operation does not take so long. (Before CTRL+T).

Comment: Do I triangulate both solids before I do the cut?

Comment: Just the one being cut.

Comment: Nope it also fails.  Edit ctrl-X ctrl-T improves the speed but the fail remain.  Thanks for the effort.

Comment: I will keep ctrl-X ctrl-T and try the other answers.